# find duplicate record in mysql without original

Tags: mysql

I want to pull out duplicate records in a MySQL Database. This can be done with:

```sql
SELECT firstname, 
   lastname, 
   list.address 
FROM list
   INNER JOIN (SELECT address
               FROM   list
               GROUP  BY address
               HAVING COUNT(id) > 1) dup
           ON list.address = dup.address;
```

Which results in:

```
JIM    JONES    100 MAIN ST
JOHN   SMITH    100 MAIN ST
```

I would like to pull it so that it shows each row that is a duplicate. Something like:

```
JIM    JONES    100 MAIN ST
```

if the result is :

```
JIM    JONES    100 MAIN ST
JOHN   SMITH    100 MAIN ST
JOHN   SMITH    100 MAIN ST
```

I would like to pull it so that it shows each row that is a duplicate. Something like:

```
JOHN   SMITH    100 MAIN ST
JOHN   SMITH    100 MAIN ST
```

I want only duplicate data not original data

Comment: Why exactly do you want to get only all duplicates?

Comment: I want to display only a duplicate element in UI. Then the user can delete an only the duplicate element in one shot. And the original element is safe for the user.

Comment: Now I see. That makes sense!

Comment: i've given a educated guess, but without table structure and or example data it's impossible to know which is the "original" (`"first"`) record .. Also SQL tables/resultsets are by SQL definition orderless without using ORDER BY clause on a deterministic column like a PRIMARY KEY with AUTO_INCREMENT option, so terms like "original", "first" option, so terms like "original", "first"  does not exists in SQL terms

Comment: .... For providing example data and expected result see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What is the PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: id is the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to find the min(id) of its related duplicate records (in your example, using *address* to associate with them). this *min(id)* will be your original one (I assume the *id* is an auto_increment PK). thus you can use id > this min(id) to find all extra duplicate records, see the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int not null auto_increment primary key,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(32),
  `lastname` VARCHAR(32),
  `address` VARCHAR(128)
);

INSERT INTO `person`
  (`firstname`, `lastname`, `address`)
VALUES
  ('Jim', 'Jones', '100 MAIN ST'),
  ('Jim', 'Smith', '100 MAIN ST'),
  ('John', 'Smith', '100 MAIN ST'),
  ('Alex', 'Smith', '23 Wall St'),
  ('Fox', 'Smith', '23 Wall St'),
  ('John', 'Smith', '100 main St');

SELECT id
,      firstname
,      lastname
,      address
FROM person p
WHERE id > (
    SELECT min(id) FROM person p1 
    WHERE p1.address = p.address
    GROUP BY p1.address
    HAVING count(*) > 1
)
```

For the sample data, this SQL will return row 2,3,5,6 as we use *address* only to check duplicates. you can adjust the sub-query to reflect a unique constraints with multiple columns, i.e. with address + lastname:

```
WHERE id > (
    SELECT min(id) FROM person p1 
    WHERE p1.address = p.address
    AND p1.lastname = p.lastname
    GROUP BY p1.address, p1.lastname
    HAVING count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: it is not working properly in 10000 records. Can u have better solutions?

Comment: It is taking 3 sec for 7000 records. so I need a faster query to find a duplicate.Can u help me.

Comment: is there an index on the `address` column or whatever columns used to join the sub-query? what does the EXPLAIN say?

Comment: SELECT * FROM document d WHERE d.report_id = 20 and d.id > (
SELECT min(d1.id) FROM document d1
WHERE d1.report_id = 20 and d1.file_name = d.file_name
and d1.file_size = d.file_size
GROUP BY d1.file_name,file_size
HAVING count(*) > 1
); 
database log -- > /* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 5,404  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 1.766 sec. (+ 47.422 sec. network) */ .

Comment: if you run `EXPLAIN` on this SELECT statement, you will see how many rows might be scanned, so you can find the bottleneck. what if you add an index on (file_name, file_size,report_id) to the table `document` if this index does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

try by using subquery

```
select * from person
where (firstname
,      lastname
,      address) in (

select firstname
,      lastname
,      address from person
group by firstname
,      lastname
,      address having count(*)>1
)
```

output

```
id  firstname   lastname    address
3   John        Smith      100 MAIN ST

6   John        Smith      100 main St
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a3e97fe6e156b1523e81d77fbf02f24e)